# Multiple upload files Rails 4 with Jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm trying to follow this tutorial, 
http://amgrade.com/blogs/thoughts/multiple-files-upload-rails and others
to make a Multiple Upload files with JQuery and Rails 4, but i'm not understanding very well.
I have already follow some tutorials and ways that i find here in stack, but none of them
could help me completely.

The models and usage of paperclip, they're fine to me, but the controllers and views
i could not  understand, unfortunately.

Does anyone have an example, or a walkthrough to get to it ?

Comment: please post your code to show what you have tryed

Comment: check out Ryan Bates episode on multi-file-uploads and look in the comments for info on how to adapt it to Rails 4. http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload. If you need more help shoot me a message.

Comment: Hi Anchieta, those examples written on the top of Rails 3, but it  should not make big difference. Please provide the code you have and point to the exact pieces, so we may help you.